# How to write XML tags of GRPO which has more than one document rows, SAP B1?

Tags: php, xml, sapb1

I have a question related to XML.
I'm not good in XML, but according to my example of tags and screenshots I can write XML tags which have CardCode and Dates of GRPO.
The problem I have now is I do know how I can include document rows in my tags
Example of tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GRPO>
 
<Goods>
<CardCode>V10000</CardCode>
<DocDate>07/11/2016</DocDate>
<DocDueDate>07/11/2016</DocDueDate>
<TaxDate>07/11/2016</TaxDate>
</Goods>
 
<Goods>
<CardCode>V1010</CardCode>
<DocDate>07/11/2016</DocDate>
<DocDueDate>07/11/2016</DocDueDate>
<TaxDate>07/11/2016</TaxDate>
</Goods>
 
</GRPO>
```

**1st screenshot**
[image]

**2nd screenshot**
[image]

I want to have the above data in XML,
How can I include document rows data in my XML tags?

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're unsure how to configure the Lines in your custom XML layout, correct?

If that's your question then you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GRPO>    
<Goods>
<CardCode>V10000</CardCode>
<DocDate>07/11/2016</DocDate>
<DocDueDate>07/11/2016</DocDueDate>
<TaxDate>07/11/2016</TaxDate>
<GoodsLines>
   <Line>
      <LineNum>0</LineNum>
      <ItemNo>A00003</ItemNo>
      <ItemDesc>J.B Officeprint 1186</ItemDesc>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
   </Line>
   <Line>
      <LineNum>1</LineNum>
      <ItemNo>A00004</ItemNo>
      <ItemDesc>Rainbow Color Printer 5.0</ItemDesc>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
   </Line>
</GoodsLines>
</Goods>        
</GRPO>
```

Another alternative is to use Attributes instead of Elements for the Line Definitions, so same as above, but something like this:

```
...
<GoodsLines>
   <Line LineNum="0" ItemNo="A00003" ItemDesc="J.B. Officeprint 1186" Quantity="4" />
   <Line LineNum="1" ItemNo="A00004" ItemDesc="Rainbow Color Printer 5.0" Quantity="5" />
</GoodsLines>
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much Overhed, that's what I wanted.